# Restore mongodb database stored in s3 bucket without loading to local machine

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a mongodb back up in an s3 bucket (tar file) and I want to restore/ import it to a mongodb cloud atlas instance without having data pass through my local machine since it is a very large file, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need some compute resource to do it. Try Lambda function. Other possibility would be an EC2 or Docker Lambda (if limitations of standard Lambda are not enough for you)